# got an issues with my dropdown menu on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some issues with my dropdown menu over on rails. I'm pretty sure my code is ok, I think the main issue is with jquery and bootstrap but then again I may be wrong. I just don't know where I am mistaken. Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WanderHomes</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if (!user_signed_in?) %>
        <li><a href="#"><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></a></li>
      <% else %>
          <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" 
              role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), class: "img-circle avatar_small"%>&nbsp;
              <%= current_user.fullname %> <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Manage Listing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">List Your Space</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Reservations</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Trips</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

This would be my application.js

```html
require('jquery')
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

Comment: Are we to guess what the issues are?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into webpack/environment.js

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', {jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'});
```

Then restart server

Hope it work !!!

Comment: Yeah, figured it out...I was using using the javascript way of rails 5 when i was on rails 6.... Thanks though :)

Comment: This si for those who have "jquery is undefined"